# Benefits of using Laravel's magic method for pass data to view?

Tags: php, laravel, view, magic-methods

What does this magic do?

```
public function index()
{
    $products = Product::all();

    return view('products.index')->withProducts($products);
}
```

There is the `View::make` way, which takes an array as a second parameter and there is the `with()` way, which takes string or an array.

```
with('products', $products);
```

or

```
with(array('products' => $products, 'foo' => $bar));
```

What is the purpose of `withModel($model)` resp. `withModels($models)`?
Are there any benefits using this approach over the other opportunities?
Also related to refactoring existing model names later on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All the different approaches accomplish the same feature, and it's a good example of Laravel's flexibility, and extensive use of magic methods.

For example, using:

```
return view('some-view')->withFooBar('some great value');
```

..is only a "faster" way to pass along a variable named `foo_bar` (snake cased, [code here](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/4.2/src/Illuminate/View/View.php)) with some specific value. This could be useful when passing along one or a few (simple) variables, but it's up to you really!